# Java unreported exception confusing me

Tags: java

Hey guys I've been working on some buttons for my GUI, and I decided to implement some previous code.

However, I'm getting an error when I try to compile. In line 141 in my code (specifically, the last button) I am told that I have an unreported `IOException` that must be caught or declared to be thrown.

My code is below:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
    if ((ae.getSource() == button5) && (!connected)) {
        try {
            s = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 2020);
            pw = new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream(), true);
        } catch (UnknownHostException uhe) {
            System.out.println(uhe.getMessage());
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            System.out.println(ioe.getMessage());
        }
        connected = true;
        t = new Thread(this);
        //b.setEnabled(false);
        button5.setLabel("Disconnect");
        t.start();
    } else if ((ae.getSource() == button5) && (connected)) {
        connected = false;
        try {
            s.close(); //no buffering so, ok
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            System.out.println(ioe.getMessage());
        }
        //System.exit(0);
        button5.setLabel("Connect");
    } else {
        temp = tf.getText();
        pw.println(temp);
        tf.setText("");
    }
    if (ae.getActionCommand().equals("Save it")) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        try {
            PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(new File("test.txt")));
            for (;;) {
                String temp = scan.nextLine();
                if (temp.equals("")) {
                    break;
                }
                pw.println(temp);
            }
            pw.close();
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            System.out.println("IO Exception! " + ioe.getMessage());
        }
    } else if (ae.getActionCommand().equals("Load it")) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        try {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("test.txt")));
            String temp = "";
            while ((temp = br.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(temp);
            }
            br.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException fnfe) {
            System.out.println("Input file not found.");
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            System.out.println("IO Exception! " + ioe.getMessage());
        }
    } else if (ae.getActionCommand().equals("Clear it")) {
        ta.setText("");
    } else {
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(new File("test.txt")));

    }
}
```

Comment: `new File()` might throw an `IOException`. Handle it like you did with the other ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just add a try/catch block to the following code (end of what you posted):

```
else{
PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter (
            new FileWriter(
            new File("test.txt")));

}}
```

like so:

```
else{
        try{
            PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter (new FileWriter(new File("test.txt")));
        } catch (Exception e) { 
            e.printStackTrace(); 
        }
}}
```

Comment: Would I put the try in my new FileWriter()?

Comment: You're declaring a `try-catch` block inside a method argument. The `try {` needs to be above the `PrintWriter`.

Comment: I'm getting an illegal start of expression try error

Comment: Okay I got it to compile, Drew Kennedy is right, just moving the try to abobe the PrintWriter will make your method work user3314809

Answer (score 0):

In general, any IO operation can potentially cause an exception. Depending on what you want, the easiest solution is just put `throws IOException` at the top of the method where you see the problem, but this isn't very good practice, and doesn't work in this case. Putting a try/catch block around the problem line, and including a meaningful error message, is probably the best way to go.

Comment: Putting `throws IOException` at the top is not even possible in this case since the `actionPerformed` method in the `ActionListener` interface does not throw an IOException.